# Asynchronous request are not always executed

Tags: asynchronous, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm currently working on some asynchronous calls.

I'm currrently experiencing an issue where sometimes calls will just do nothing and don't throw an error or something.

It happens like once, twice in like 20-30 calls.

This is what I currently have.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hAppServer AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

hAppServer = getServersHandle(AppSrvConnectionEnum:apsvWorkFlow).    

RUN ServiceInterface/StartAsync.p ON SERVER hAppServer ASYNCHRONOUS EVENT-PROCEDURE "ProcedureComplete" IN hCallBack  (INPUT ipiWorkflowId).
```

I'm running it on Progress Version 11.6.4. I also have put messages on the `ServiceInterface/StartAsync.p` procedure, and when the calls do not get through no messages are written to the appserver ofcourse.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Any errors appearing in the Appserver log file?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you might have a dead reference to the server. Just for debugging, try to message valid-handle(hAppServer) and hAppServer itself, since I suspect at some point it's returning an invalid reference (though I imagine the enum is not changed during runtime). Nothing wrong in the code you posted, at first look.

Comment: The ```getServerHandle``` method actually already checks this before returning a valid handle.

Comment: But did you message the handle itself? Does it change in the instances where the call doesn't hit the server?